# How to switch between the graphics on Acer Nitro 5 with AMD Ryzen and Radeon 560x

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

How to switch between the graphics on Acer Nitro 5 with AMD Ryzen Vega (Raven) and Radeon 560x?

[image: "About" screenshot]

~$ xrandr --listproviders

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x7a cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:Unknown AMD Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:04:00.0
Provider 1: id: 0x44 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:AMD Radeon (TM) RX Graphics @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

~$ DRI_PRIME=0 glmark2

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     X.Org
    GL_RENDERER:   AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.23.0 / 4.15.0-38-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 1998 FrameTime: 0.501 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 2181 FrameTime: 0.459 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 2132 FrameTime: 0.469 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 2133 FrameTime: 0.469 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 2072 FrameTime: 0.483 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 1873 FrameTime: 0.534 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 1869 FrameTime: 0.535 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 1859 FrameTime: 0.538 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 1867 FrameTime: 0.536 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 1362 FrameTime: 0.734 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 2038 FrameTime: 0.491 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 2112 FrameTime: 0.473 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 1655 FrameTime: 0.604 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 1400 FrameTime: 0.714 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 1851 FrameTime: 0.540 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 1210 FrameTime: 0.826 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 1557 FrameTime: 0.642 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 641 FrameTime: 1.560 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 864 FrameTime: 1.157 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 606 FrameTime: 1.650 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 1504 FrameTime: 0.665 ms
[jellyfish] : FPS: 1363 FrameTime: 0.734 ms
[terrain] : FPS: 216 FrameTime: 4.630 ms
[shadow] : FPS: 1624 FrameTime: 0.616 ms
[refract] : FPS: 346 FrameTime: 2.890 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2244 FrameTime: 0.446 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2231 FrameTime: 0.448 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1987 FrameTime: 0.503 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 1911 FrameTime: 0.523 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 1739 FrameTime: 0.575 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2256 FrameTime: 0.443 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2016 FrameTime: 0.496 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2216 FrameTime: 0.451 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 1664 
=======================================================
```

~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     X.Org
    GL_RENDERER:   AMD Radeon (TM) RX Graphics (POLARIS11 / DRM 3.23.0 / 4.15.0-38-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 550 FrameTime: 1.818 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 551 FrameTime: 1.815 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 556 FrameTime: 1.799 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 546 FrameTime: 1.832 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 547 FrameTime: 1.828 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 561 FrameTime: 1.783 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 560 FrameTime: 1.786 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 561 FrameTime: 1.783 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 561 FrameTime: 1.783 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 561 FrameTime: 1.783 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 559 FrameTime: 1.789 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 559 FrameTime: 1.789 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 559 FrameTime: 1.789 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 558 FrameTime: 1.792 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 559 FrameTime: 1.789 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 563 FrameTime: 1.776 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 563 FrameTime: 1.776 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 537 FrameTime: 1.862 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 537 FrameTime: 1.862 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 554 FrameTime: 1.805 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 540 FrameTime: 1.852 ms
[jellyfish] : FPS: 550 FrameTime: 1.818 ms
[terrain] : FPS: 406 FrameTime: 2.463 ms
[shadow] : FPS: 554 FrameTime: 1.805 ms
[refract] : FPS: 501 FrameTime: 1.996 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 553 FrameTime: 1.808 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 558 FrameTime: 1.792 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 555 FrameTime: 1.802 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 545 FrameTime: 1.835 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 553 FrameTime: 1.808 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 554 FrameTime: 1.805 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 549 FrameTime: 1.821 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 554 FrameTime: 1.805 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 547 
=======================================================
```

I have the same issue. iGPU performs better than dGPU. dGPU has the potential to be better than iGPU right?

Comment: The same issue here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470351/rx-560x-slower-than-integrated-vega-gpu-on-fedora-28

Comment: Sorry out of topic, but how do you setup the GPU? are you installing the drivers? sicnce the rx560x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according this article:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470351/rx-560x-slower-than-integrated-vega-gpu-on-fedora-28

test if you see you dedicated gpu using lspci
or if the dedicated gpu is recognized:
xrandr --listdevices
If so run:

DRI_PRIME=0 glmark2 - for integrated
DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2 - for dedicated

not sure if running on Ubuntu, but you can tell then since I have no time to install it on my AN515-42 because of this.
Btw is working everything else fine?

Comment: No there is this issue too : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092288/ubuntu-18-04-is-taking-long-to-load

Comment: The dGPU performs worse than the iGPU. Is this because of the drivers?

Comment: I think I can see the performance of both the cards. How can I switch them for all applicatons?

Comment: I think you mean `--listproviders`, not `--listdevices`.