# Ubuntu 18.04 is taking long to load

Tags: boot

$ systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 4.251s (firmware) + 2.465s (loader) + 1min 42.939s (kernel) + 37.609s (userspace) = 2min 27.266s
graphical.target reached after 37.467s in userspace
```

$ systemd-analyze blame

```
         19.962s dev-sda6.device
         19.857s systemd-journal-flush.service
         18.791s keyboard-setup.service
         11.982s systemd-udevd.service
          8.832s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          7.820s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.354s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          3.216s snapd.service
          3.099s ModemManager.service
          2.899s udisks2.service
          2.565s thermald.service
          2.513s NetworkManager.service
          2.437s networkd-dispatcher.service
          2.356s fwupd.service
          2.353s accounts-daemon.service
          2.193s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-148F\x2d75AB.service
          1.895s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d3ac8189\x2de076\x2d4ea7\x2dad
          1.846s networking.service
          1.365s gpu-manager.service
          1.298s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.158s plymouth-start.service
          1.091s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-65331ba5\x2d436a\x2d4a88\x2d9a59\x2defea07c
           848ms grub-common.service
           767ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           763ms dev-mqueue.mount
           756ms bluetooth.service
           748ms packagekit.service
           704ms dev-hugepages.mount
           696ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           658ms wpa_supplicant.service
           559ms apport.service
           548ms systemd-journald.service
           543ms rsyslog.service
           518ms avahi-daemon.service
           508ms pppd-dns.service
           502ms polkit.service
           438ms apparmor.service
           435ms gdm.service
           380ms colord.service
           337ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           309ms systemd-sysctl.service
           290ms dns-clean.service
           208ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           189ms systemd-rfkill.service
           182ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           182ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           175ms user@121.service
           173ms systemd-logind.service
           170ms upower.service
           159ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           155ms systemd-random-seed.service
           141ms setvtrgb.service
           135ms systemd-resolved.service
           124ms user@1000.service
           122ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
           120ms plymouth-read-write.service
           107ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
            92ms bolt.service
            90ms snap-core-4917.mount
            87ms home.mount
            82ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
            69ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
            64ms speech-dispatcher.service
            62ms ufw.service
            60ms alsa-restore.service
            47ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
            39ms boot-efi.mount
            27ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
            19ms rtkit-daemon.service
            13ms kerneloops.service
            10ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl1.service
             9ms snapd.seeded.service
             8ms ureadahead-stop.service
             7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             7ms dev-loop3.device
             6ms dev-loop2.device
             6ms dev-loop1.device
             6ms dev-loop0.device
             4ms console-setup.service
             3ms dev-loop6.device
             3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             3ms dev-loop5.device
             3ms dev-loop4.device
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             974us snapd.socket
```

name -a

```
Linux nitro-AN515-42 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.
graphical.target @30.886s
└─multi-user.target @30.886s
  └─kerneloops.service @30.870s +15ms
    └─network-online.target @30.868s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @24.018s +6.849s
        └─NetworkManager.service @21.653s +2.362s
          └─dbus.service @20.975s
            └─basic.target @20.944s
              └─sockets.target @20.944s
                └─snapd.socket @20.939s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @20.935s
                    └─apparmor.service @20.536s +396ms
                      └─local-fs.target @20.532s
                        └─run-user-121.mount @24.846s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @19.078s
                            └─keyboard-setup.service @2.381s +16.696s
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @2.341s
                                └─system.slice @2.340s
                                  └─-.slice @2.337s
```

I use Ubuntu dual booted with Windows in Acer Nitro 5 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

ADDING this to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2

solved the problem for me on the same laptop.

interverting the [4] and the [5] lead to kernel hang.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your kernel is the one to blame here, can you please paste the return of `uname -a` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` ?

Comment: Ok, I've posted it.